# Where can I get ProGuard for Eclipse?

Tags: java, proguard

I've googled ProGuard for eclipse and all I can find is the Android version. I found one that looked like it would work but I found out it was out dated and their website was not even online anymore.

Anyone know where I can get eclipse to be able to export configurations so I can obfuscate my Jar files using ProGuard? This is all in Java by the way.

Comment: I've yet to see a valid reason for jar file obfuscation in my 15 years of Java programming. If the code is bad (as it often is), nobody will want it. If the code is good, obfuscation won't help.

Comment: I know people are going to want my code, it's a program which allows me to automatically post stuff to my website. If someone altered it or just made their own even using pieces of my code they could use it to spam my site, or many other forums like mine. It took me awhile to get it all working due to having to make my own captcha solver and stuff... Pretty complex. But yeah I see what you mean, you wouldn't obfuscate something that is just useless :p

Answer (score 1):

1) Add next line of code to your `project.properties` file in project folder:

```
proguard.config=proguard.cfg
```

2) Create `proguard.cfg` file in project folder with your proguard configuration

Here you can find example of proguard configuration for Android application  [Proguard manual page](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/examples.html)

3) Compile your application using `Ant` [Building and Running from the Command Line](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is bundled with [Pulsar](http://www.eclipse.org/pulsar/).
It shuld be as a plugin, but it has broken link now.